# Multiple row values into one for repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If ID is repeating i have to move the 
values of C (row 1) to Column 1 and values of D (row 1) to column 2,
values of C (row 2) to Column 3 and values of D (row 2) to column 4,
values of C (row 3) to Column 5 and values of D (row 3) to column 6,
Is there a way we can do it in sql

Thank You

```
ID  B   C       D   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   Hat Device1 34                      
2   Mat Device2 65                      
3   Cat Device3 76                      
3   Sat Device4 34                      
3   Hat Device5 89                      
4   Hat Device6 23                      
4   Hat Device7 12      



ID  B   1       2   3      4    5   6
1   Hat Device1 34              
2   Mat Device2 65              
3   Cat Device3 76  Device4 34  Device5 89
4   Hat Device6 23
```

Comment: I literally have no idea how that data is meant to be aligned. Please can you make it understandable. Or, even better, provide `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Why is CAT for ID3 and not HAT?

Comment: @Larnu  The grouping is done on the `ID` column.  Note the duplicate `ID` vales in the first dataset that are removed in the second.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If this is to store data back into the database I would strongly recommend rethinking your design.  If this is for presentation in a report, leave the pivoting to the presentation layer you are reporting with.

Comment: We send it as export to a client using ssis, cannot change database values, have to do it on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #input (ID INT, B VARCHAR(10), C VARCHAR(15), D INT, [1] VARCHAR(15), [2] INT, [3] VARCHAR(15), [4] INT,[5] VARCHAR(15), [6] INT)
CREATE TABLE #output (ID INT, B VARCHAR(10), [1] VARCHAR(15), [2] INT, [3] VARCHAR(15), [4] INT, [5] VARCHAR(15), [6] INT)

INSERT INTO #input (ID,B,C,D)
VALUES (1,'Hat', 'Device1', 34 )

INSERT INTO #input (ID,B,C,D)
VALUES (2,'Mat', 'Device2', 65 )

INSERT INTO #input (ID,B,C,D)
VALUES (3,'Cat', 'Device3', 76 )

INSERT INTO #input (ID,B,C,D)
VALUES (3,'Sat', 'Device4', 34 )

INSERT INTO #input (ID,B,C,D)
VALUES (3,'Hat', 'Device5', 89 )

INSERT INTO #input (ID,B,C,D)
VALUES (4,'Hat', 'Device6', 76 )

INSERT INTO #input (ID,B,C,D)
VALUES (4,'Hat', 'Device7', 12 )

DECLARE 
    @id INT,
    @b VARCHAR(10),
    @c VARCHAR(15),
    @d INT



    DECLARE input CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, B, C, D FROM #input
    OPEN input
    FETCH NEXT FROM input INTO @id, @b, @c, @d
    WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
    BEGIN

        IF @id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM #output)
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO #output (ID,B,[1],[2])
            VALUES (@id, @b, @c, @d )

        END
        ELSE IF @id IN (SELECT ID FROM #output) AND (SELECT [3] FROM #output WHERE ID = @id) IS NULL
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #output 
            SET [3] = @c,
            [4] = @d
            WHERE ID = @id
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #output 
            SET [5] = @c,
            [6] = @d
            WHERE ID = @id
        END

            FETCH NEXT FROM input INTO @id, @b, @c, @d
    END
    CLOSE input
    DEALLOCATE input

SELECT * FROM #input
SELECT * FROM #output
DROP TABLE #input
DROP TABLE #output
```

You can try this here :

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=bb3f59d0df1ddfdfba8d31c38b742919

Comment: Thank you, it is what was expected.

Comment: I m glad that I could help, 
if you need explanation, ask :) @aman6496

Comment: If you can choose that this answer is correct, if someone had a similar problem in the future. Have nice day :) @aman6496

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, min(b) as b,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then c end) as [1],
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then d end) as [2],
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then c end) as [3],
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then d end) as [4],
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then c end) as [5],
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then d end) as [6]
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```